# I update kohana 3.0.5->3.1.1 error

Tags: kohana-3, hmvc

I followed the example http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2010/02/25/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-5/

I get the following error:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property:Response::$response.
APPPATH\views\pages\hmvc.php [ 2 ].
```

I don’t know how to fix it. Can you offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ko3.1 `execute()` method returns Response object. You must use `echo Request::factory('posts/getposts')->execute()->body()` or just `echo Request::factory('posts/getposts')->execute()`.

Follow [this tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading) to upgrade your Kohana app.